# System.load throws NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java

I am trying to load a native library on windows using JRE 1.7. Here is my code to load the library:

```
public boolean loadNativeLibrary(String libName){
    try{
        String libPath = RLibLocator.locateLibrary(libName);
        File tmpLibPath = File.createTempFile("lib", ".dll");
        InputStream libIn = PlatformGeneric.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(libPath);
        byte[] decrypted = AES.decrypt(StreamUtils.readAll(libIn), RLibLocator.LIB_DATA_KEY);
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(tmpLibPath);
        fout.write(decrypted);
        fout.flush();
        libIn.close();
        fout.close();
        tmpLibPath.deleteOnExit();
        System.load(tmpLibPath.getAbsolutePath());
        return true;
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("Platform/LibLoader", "Failed to load library: Exception: " + e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
        if(DEBUG)
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

As you can see, the library being loaded is encrypted and then decrypted on runtime and loaded using `System.load`. However, when running this code, the pplication throws a `NoSuchMethodError`. The stack trace is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: <init>
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
    at PlatformGeneric.loadNativeLibrary(PlatformGeneric.java:225)
    ...
```

I have checked that the decrypted library being stored in the temporary folder is the same as the non-encrypted, initially compiled binary (ther hashes match). The library I am trying to load definitely has no errors and the source can be found here: https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook.

Am I doing anything wrong here? If so, how can I fix this?

**NOTE:**
I have tried running this using multiple JREs (1.5-1.8).

Comment: It looks like it's having a problem loading a class from within the native library. Is there a Java library (i.e., .class or .jar file) associated with the native library you're trying to load? There usually is, and make sure it's in your classpath.

Comment: Include the folder containing the lib.dll in your java classpath

Comment: I have made sure all of the necessary classes are on the classpath. Is there any other possible cause of this error? @MikeHarris

Comment: This is not a classpath or a java library path issue.  The code you have appears to be correct, however, there is not enough information in your post to determine what the problem is.  I suspect that the file pointed to by `tmpLibPath.getAbsolutePath()` is somehow incorrect for you runtime environment.  Maybe the wrong arch or botched decryption.  What is inside of RLibLocator.locateLibrary(libName)?

Comment: It is the correct architecture and the hash of the decrypted file matches the hash of the file which was never decrypted. @AlexBarker. I have figured out that it was indeed a classpath error as instead of extracting the source from the zip I downloaded from github, I instead added the JNativeHook jar to my eclipse project and it worked when compiled. Thanks for the replies.